# How to use flink window api to apply an aggregate function on a stream window per second

Tags: streaming, apache-flink

I want to apply function `sum` on a stream window which period is an hour and the function execute per seconds.
For example:
the current window is  13:00:00-14:59:59 and the current time is 13:00:03 .
13:00:04 : `sum` on  13:00:00- 13:00:04
13:00:05 : `sum` on  13:00:00- 13:00:05
.
.
.
13:59:59: `sum` on  13:00:00- 13:59:59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility to implement this is by using a [`ProcessFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/stream/process_function.html). The function allows you to set timers that could e.g. fire every second. The intermediate results of your computation can be stored in a [state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/stream/state.html#using-managed-keyed-state) (e.g. `ListState` or `ValueState`).

Another way could be by implementing a custom `Trigger`. Triggers define when to evaluate a pane of a window, the content itself is not affected unless you also define a custom evictor. [Here](https://gist.github.com/mxm/c5831ead9c9d9ad68731f5f2f3793154) is an example of a trigger.